# Android search in html file

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, search

I am trying to search html files in a ebook app which is using android webview to display html books
i tried using javascript search but its too slow for a 7 mb html file with more than 6000 div's to search 
and it hangs the app is there any way so that i can search in the android app in the html files and display results in the same manner as this js code i was using for small sized html
the code is running on jsfiddle please check  http://jsfiddle.net/E2uLD/1/
 following is the code i am using right now

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var results = $("#resultContainer");
var text = $("#search").val();
results.empty();
$.get("ebook.html", function (data) {
var els = $(data).find("div:contains(" + text + ")").appendTo(results);
els.find('a').contents().unwrap();
els.wrap(function(){
    return $('<a/>', {
        href: 'ebook.html#' +this.id
      })
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is in an Android WebView consider using the setJavaScriptEnabled ie, webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); This will allow you to grab the HTML and look into it using java, or pass the search value to the android code and do a dot contains inside of the webview. Good Luck!

Example here: [java script enabled for webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: am already using this code in a android app but its only useful for small html files but i need to search big size html files that are upto 7 mb  the code is taking around 20 sec in chrome to display results while in app its crashing the app any alternative ??

Comment: You could take the HTML store it in SQLite and query that way. 7mb file, that is a lot even for a desktop browser to load and search thru. I would look at storing the html in a table and query that way.

Comment: if i store that in sqlite some functionality will be disturbed like browse for the ebook and also div id header  so cant acctually use sqlite also it has inline links

Comment: i will be using this offline so first load is taking just 5 seconds after that i need the search to be instant

Comment: or atleast it should perform in background and display results in realtime

Comment: I would really look at using the search feature in the android webview  this feature has a findAll(TEXT TO FIND) method that will do the look up for you.

Comment: :) find a word is already one of functionality of app and is working perfectly  this is meant for a better search i need results displayed in a seperate page and then linked to main page as in jsfiddle i posted